# Does producres create symbol of a new token or we can create ourself?

Tags: tokens, ico, token-registration

On the test net we provide permission to a account to create a symbol for a new token like this:

```
void create(account_name issuer, string symbol);
```

After that we issue the tokens.

But on the main net , How this process work? How token symbols are generated and Who provide the permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process works same as on test net with one change that is you need to provide authorization via mainnet account. Producers don't create symbole for your token you need to do it by yourself only as you do it on testnet.

Comment: So I have to create symbol for myself , mean the account that set the contract , can create symbol for himself, and issue the symbol to any account

Comment: this sounds  good ..

Comment: yeah thats true...